# R Skip to Next Record if Value Already Exists in Database

Tags: sql-server, r, for-loop, rodbc

I'm banging my head against a wall here trying to figure this out...  I have a script that if the game_id already exists in the table I'm writing to I would like to skip to the next record in the loop

```
  #Connect to db
saber <- odbcConnect("sabermetrics")

  #query to pull all existing game records
check_query <- paste0("select distinct game_id from allbats")

  #build variables to compare db field and game_id in current url
game_id_check <- sqlQuery(saber, check_query)
curr_gameid <- substr(thisboxscoreURL, 66, 95)

  #if they match sktip to next record
if(game_id_check == curr_gameid) next
```

I've tried matrixing the data, listing, unlisting, combinations to get the data to "match", and failed miserably EVERYWHERE!

I could probably put the game_id from the url in the where clause of the query string and if the count is greater than 0 then skip to the next record as well.  I'm not sure which one would be better, probably the latter because I would only return one value at most for each record in the loop.

something like

```
  #Connect to db
saber <- odbcConnect("sabermetrics")

  #query to pull all existing game records
check_query <- paste0("select distinct game_id from allbats where game_id = url_game_id")

if(count(sqlquery(saber, check_query)))>0 next
```

example data

```
away    home    inning  away_team_code  home_team_code  game_id

0         0       1        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         0       2        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         0       3        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         0       4        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         1       5        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         0       6        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         0       7        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         0       8        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
0         x       9        sdn            sfn           gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1
```

Here is the dput, not sure it's useful though.

```
dput(sqlQuery(saber, "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM allbats"))
structure(list(away = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), home = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "x"), class = "factor"), 
inning = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L), away_team_code = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("hou", "mia", "sdn"), class = "factor"), 
home_team_code = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("lan", 
"sea", "sfn"), class = "factor"), game_id = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("gid_2016_04_26_houmlb_seamlb_1", 
"gid_2016_04_26_miamlb_lanmlb_1", "gid_2016_04_26_sdnmlb_sfnmlb_1"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("away", "home", "inning", 
"away_team_code", "home_team_code", "game_id"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be aprreciated!!  Thanks!

Comment: Which database backend are you using (SQL Server, SQLite, ...)?

Comment: I am using sql server for the backend

Comment: And you are trying to insert new records into the database table only if the `game_id` of the new record does not already exist in the table? Also, can you provide a sample of your data to clarify the structure of the table (e.g., paste the output of `dput(sqlquery(saber, "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM allbats"))` into your question)?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, insert if the game_id doesn't exist in the table.  I attached example data to my original post. Thanks for your help @nrussell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it using the sqldf package

```
saber <- odbcConnect("sabermetrics")

existingGames <- paste0("select distinct game_id from linescore")
newGames <- data.frame(gameids)

existingGames <- sqlQuery(saber, existingGames)

require(sqldf)

  # Get all new games that do not exist in existing games (linescore table)
ngNotIneg <- sqldf('SELECT distinct * FROM newGames EXCEPT SELECT distinct * FROM existingGames')

odbcClose(saber)
```